# ajax PUT does not transfer array

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, rest

I use javascript in my webpage to send a GUID (url parameter) + a GUID array to the webservice.
But when I try to send the GUID array, the parameter stays everytime empty.

my Javascript looks like this:

```
//Save Button is clicked
function saveBtnClicked() {
    var currentDataSetGuid = $("#currentDataSetGuid").val();
    var Table = $("#Table").find("tbody").first();
    var selectedElements = Table.find("input:checked");
    var saveGuidArray = new Array();
    var i = 0;
    while (i < selectedElements.length) {
        var trid = selectedElements[i].parentElement.parentElement.id;
        saveGuidArray.push(trid);
        i = i + 1;
    }

    putSave(currentDataSetGuid,saveGuidArray)
}

//Save action to call the controller
function putSave(currentDataSetGuid, saveGuidArray) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        method: "PUT",
        url: "/api/myAPP/SaveEndpoint/" + currentDataSetGuid,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ paramName: saveGuidArray}),
        success: function (result) {
            showSuccess("Save was successfull");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            showError("Error while saving");
        }
    });
}
```

I also tried - but with the same result:

```
data: JSON.stringify(saveGuidArray),
```

And here is my implementation of the Controller Interface (C#)

```
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("/api/myAPP/SaveEndpoint/{currentDataSetGuid}")]
    public IActionResult SaveAction(Guid currentDataSetGuid, List<Guid> saveGuidArray)
```

> In my controller, currentDataSetGuid is set every time correctly. 
>   But saveGuidArray is empty / has no elements.

Comment: Just do: data: { paramName: saveGuidArray}

Comment: @programmer-man - sorry but the List in the controller is still empty

Comment: What does console.log(saveGuidArray) output ?

Comment: the output is: 293c0409-3340-e911-811c-0050c0187087,459e5b6a-3440-e911-811c-0050c0187087,7fae159c-4540-e911-811c-0050c0187087

Comment: Can you also show the code that called putSave() ?

Comment: I added the code to the original post

Comment: Have you actually written `paramName` in your Ajax call? AFAIK, you should use the actual name of the parameter in the controller

Comment: I changed the ajax parametername and also the property in the c# controller, but it sill stayes null

Comment: @Twiebie Try: data: { saveGuidArray: saveGuidArray }
And replace "List<Guid> saveGuidArray" with "List<string> saveGuidArray"

Comment: I tried it as a List<string> and also IEnumerable<String> but both are null

Comment: I resolved the issue. I added the resolution and will mark it in 2 days as answer.
Thx for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the error now.
The problem was a plain datatype as HTTP Body.

I added a new class and implemented the controller accordingly.

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("/api/myAPP/SaveEndpoint/{currentDataSetGuid}")]
public IActionResult SaveAction(Guid currentDataSetGuid, [FromBody] ViewSaveGuid saveGuidArray)
```

And then I setup the object in the javascript to pass it as JSON.Stringify

```
var GuidList{
   array: saveGuidArray
};
[...]
data: JSON.stringify(GuidList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you have your action defined like this:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("/api/myAPP/SaveEndpoint/{currentDataSetGuid}")]
public IActionResult SaveAction(Guid currentDataSetGuid, [FromBody]List<Guid> saveGuidArray)
```

Then your Ajax request should be formatted this way:

```
function putSave(currentDataSetGuid, saveGuidArray) {
  if (!currentDataSetGuid || !saveGuidArray) {
    console.log('Error');
    // Handle validation
    return;
  }

  $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      cache: false,
      method: "PUT",
      url: "/api/myAPP/SaveEndpoint/" + currentDataSetGuid,
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: JSON.stringify({ saveGuidArray }), // Take note of the difference on this line.
      success: function (result) {
          showSuccess("Save was successfull");
      },
      error: function (error) {
          showError("Error while saving");
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried it the way ypi suggested, but the array stays "null"

Comment: Could you also include the html code that `saveBtnClicked` works on?

Comment: I could, but the HTML is realy huge / a lot of effort to extract the needed parts. 
If it helps you, when I log saveGuidArray befor the ajax is send, the log output is: 293c0409-3340-e911-811c-0050c0187087,459e5b6a-3440-e911-811c-0050c0187087,7fae159c-4540-e911-811c-0050c0187087

So IMO it is a valid array

Comment: I think your `Guid` model doesn't match the type that it receives. You can place a debugger on that line to inspect what is coming in.

Comment: I resolved the issue. I added the resolution and will mark it in 2 days as answer.
Thx for your help.